# Stopped service does not release its resources?

Tags: windows, file, service, locking

I'm trying to deploy a patch to a service I created and replace the service file.
For that reason I need to stop the service so the file will be released.
I'm using `sc \\remote stop svcname`, then I query the service using `sc \\remote query svcname` until I see that it's state is STOPPED.
At this point the service file should be unlocked, and to be on the safe side I also delete the service using `sc \\remote delete svcname`.

Still, it doesn't seem to release the file and any deletion or change attempt fails.
I know one solution might be polling the file repeatedly, but I want to avoid this method.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows don't ensure the process providing the service terminates when the service is stopped (the process may provide more than one service). It just considers the service stopped when it handles the message sent to it.

So if the service process has a bug and does not properly release resources, they may still be locked. I would probably wait a little and than simply terminate the process.

There is also a tool from Microsoft called [handle.exe](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655.aspx) (this is command-line version, they also have a GUI-one) that can list which processes hold the file open. It should be possible to get the same information programmatically, but I am not sure of the exact calls to make (and you need administrator privileges; you have to give them to the tool too). That way you can check whether the file is open, by which process and wait for it to terminate or force-terminate it if you didn't know which one it is.

Comment: Thanks! I assumed STOP_PENDING was when the service requested the stop, and the STOPPED is when it actually terminated. Doesn't make sense to have a STOPPED if it's still there. Anyways if that's the case I don't see any other way than to poll it repeatedly like I wanted to avoid doing.

Comment: It isn't documented, but for services that don't share executables (SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS) the service control dispatcher does in fact exit the process when the status is set to SERVICE_STOPPED; the call to SetServiceStatus never returns.  However, the service manager probably does not actually wait for the process to finish exiting before reporting the status as SERVICE_STOPPED.

Comment: @YarivLivay: QueryServiceStatusEx allows you to retrieve the process ID for the service.  You can then use OpenProcess and WaitForSingleObject to wait for the process to exit, rather than polling.